# postgres jsonb update array element based on different array element

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update

I want to update `ContextItems` where `id=993`, changing label from 'Jane's Trucking' to 'newname'.

I do not want other data to change.

Initial data:

```json
{  
    "UserId": "JohnDoe",
    "ContextItems": "{\"Entity\":{\"items\":[{\"id\":993,\"label\":\"Jane's Trucking\",\"viewModelId\":\"EntityEdit\"},{\"id\":992,\"label\":\"Bob's Flowers\",\"viewModelId\":\"EntityEdit\"}],\"targetView\":\"EntityViewEdit\"}}"
}
```

I have managed to manipulate data,  however, the layout has changed from above to json:

```json
[{
    "viewmodelid": "EntityEdit",
    "id": "993",
    "label": "newname"
},{
    "viewmodelid": "EntityEdit",
    "id": "992",
    "label": "Bob's Flowers"
}]
```

This is the code that achieved this. What else is needed to convert back from json to what I guess was some sort of text in `ContextItems`?

```
with temp1 as 
    (select (jsondoc_->'ContextItems' #>> '{}')::jsonb ->'Entity'-->'items'
     as jsonfield , id_ , jsondoc_ from usersetting    where id_='21|77')   
, temp2 as  
    (select obj->>'label' as label, obj->>'id' as id, obj->>'viewModelId' as viewModelId,    id_ 
                    from temp1,   jsonb_array_elements(temp1.jsonfield->'items')  obj(val)   )
, temp3 as
    (select id, case when id='993' then 'newname' else label end as label ,viewModelId  
     from temp2)
select   json_agg(temp3) as origjson FROM temp3 where id in ('993','992')
```

Comment: Normalize the data model, then this will be straightforward and efficient. Avoid JSON if you have such requirements.

Comment: it is already in JSON, this cannot be changed.  :-(   The tricky bit appears to be that ContextItems is stored as a string within the larger json.   If I cast jsondoc_::text, I can use regexp to do the replacement, but replacing this string leaves backslashes that json cannot ingest: ```  {\"items\":[{\"id\":993,\"label\":\"Jane's Trucking\",\"viewModelId\":\"EntityEdit\"}  ```  replacing just the label works, but this would need to be conditional on id=993 and am not sure how to write that in regexp_replace